# Laravel Eloquent Internal Server Error Trace

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Having problems inserting data into a table. Other tables working nice with eloquent queries.

1. My HTML form's POST working nice. I can get another kind of responses.
2. My form's route working nice. No problem about that.
3. **My problem is when i trying to insert data on "myTable" table, I get Internal Server Error 500 and i cannot trace what it is. Even laravel debugbar cannot help me.**

Routes.php

```
Route::post('submitForm', array(
    'uses' => 'FormController@submitForm',
    'as' => 'submitForm'
));
```

FormController.php

```
<?php
class FormController extends BaseController{
    public function submitForm(){
        try{ 
            $formModel = new myModel;
            $formModel->projectName = 'asdasd';
            $formModel.save();
            echo('done.');
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

myModel.php

```
<?php
class myModel extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'myTable';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = array('projectName');
}
```

4. **In my table "myTable", i have an auto incrementing id field which is not null.**
5. **If you cannot help me at least i wanna learn how to trace database-based errors.** Because only i get is a white screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I think the problem might be using:

```
$formModel.save();
```

it should be rather:

```
$formModel->save();
```

Comment: Yes this is the answer, but i still want to trace what is going on, i would like to see an error. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: @DemonDrake do you have `debug` set to `true` for your environment?

Comment: Yes it is set as true.

Comment: @DemonDrake So if you BEFORE this code add for example `echo $aaa;` (and `$aaa` does not exist) you are getting stack trace with information `Undefined variable: aaa `?

Comment: Yes i am getting this kind of error but these errors are laravel-based. When i get white screen i understand there's something wrong with database-side.

Comment: @DemonDrake It's rather not database related error. If it were, you would also get trace for this. This might be some specific case because normally you shouldn't get server error in this case but PHP warning/error. Maybe someone else will know more about it.